# ConfirmAccount Extension Fix Failed

Tags: mediawiki

I attempted a fix on [ConfirmAccount extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount), but my fix did not seem to work. Any suggestions?

**Details:**

"pruning of old requests will not trigger often, so old rejected requests may persist."
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount#Known_issues

This behavior will prevent rejected emails from requesting an account again. After Admin rejected an account request, the same username/email could not submit another request. Error on 2nd attempt:

> Username is already in use in a pending account request.

We want to enable re-requests. To fix, i want to force prune after every rejection, to clear the request cache.

It appears that, currently, pruning occurs in file **\extensions\ConfirmAccount\frontend\specialpages\actions\ConfirmAccount_body.php**

```
# Every 30th view, prune old deleted items
if ( 0 == mt_rand( 0, 29 ) ) {
ConfirmAccount::runAutoMaintenance();
}
```

Therefor, the function `runAutoMaintenance` appears to be the pruning function. `runAutoMaintenance` lives in **\ConfirmAccount\backend\ConfirmAccount.class.php**

```
class ConfirmAccount {
/** * Move old stale requests to rejected list. Delete old rejected requests. */
public static function runAutoMaintenance() {
...
```

In order to call `runAutoMaintenance` after every reject-action, I think the call to `runAutoMaintenance` should be placed in function `rejectRequest`, in file **\extensions\ConfirmAccount\business\AccountConfirmSubmission.php**

Specifically, i think it can go directly under:

```
# Clear cache for notice of how many account requests there are
ConfirmAccount::clearAccountRequestCountCache();
```

Maybe pruning should also happen after Accept, Hold, and Spam actions. Unsure. For now, pruning after Reject should handle the original problem.

I attempted the above fix, and it did not seem to work. I'm at a loss.

Can someone help determine why this fix did not work?

**Original code:**

```
protected function rejectRequest( IContextSource $context ) {
....
# Clear cache for notice of how many account requests there are
ConfirmAccount::clearAccountRequestCountCache();
....
```

**New code:**

```
protected function rejectRequest( IContextSource $context ) {
....
# Clear cache for notice of how many account requests there are
ConfirmAccount::clearAccountRequestCountCache();
# Prune
ConfirmAccount::runAutoMaintenance();
....
```

On 2nd request, still getting "Username is already in use in a pending account request."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i solved it. There are 2 steps:

- Set rejected items to expire immediately (in **LocalSettings.php**)
- Prune rejected items at beginning of Request action (in **RequestAccount_body.php**)

**Details:**

in **LocalSettings.php,** after required declaration, set Rejected-Age to 0. That ensures rejected requests will be removed on prune-action:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/ConfirmAccount/ConfirmAccount.php";
$wgRejectedAccountMaxAge = 0;
```

Add Prune code to the function that shows the Request form, in /ConfirmAccount/frontend/specialpages/actions/**RequestAccount_body.php, function showForm.** Add very last command in the function:

**old code:**

```
$out->addWikiMsg( 'requestaccount-footer' );
}
```

**new code:**

```
$out->addWikiMsg( 'requestaccount-footer' );        
# PRUNE
ConfirmAccount::runAutoMaintenance();
}
```